# Absolute path in application.yml

Tags: spring-boot, path

I am having some troubles in order to specify the absolute path of some resources in the application.yml of my spring boot app.

Using relative path works ok, I place those files under src/main/resources/key with the following configuration:

```
public:
  encryption:
    key: keys\encrypt\public_enc_asn1.key
  decryption:
    key: keys\decrypt\public_dec_asn1.key
private:
  decryption:
    key: keys\decrypt\private_dec_asn1.key
```

I am using windows. I put the same files under C:\test\ with the following configs in application.yml but they are not working:

```
public:
  encryption:
    key: C:\test\encrypt\public_enc_asn1.key
  decryption:
    key: C:\test\decrypt\public_dec_asn1.key
private:
  decryption:
    key: C:\test\decrypt\private_dec_asn1.key
```

How can I specify a windows absolute path in application.yml? I also tried with `${user.home}` option but no luck.

Comment: Can you show the code around how you are using that key? Are you asking for Spring to convert it to a URI or something up front or are you taking the raw string and doing something with it in the code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The error is due to colon in your values (as in `C:\test\...`). You need to surround your value with quotes:

```
public:
  encryption:
    key: 'C:\test\encrypt\public_enc_asn1.key'
  decryption:
    key: 'C:\test\decrypt\public_dec_asn1.key'
private:
  decryption:
    key: 'C:\test\decrypt\private_dec_asn1.key'
```

Answer (score 2):

I was working on a project on Kafka with spring boot and was getting error when provided an absolute path. As mentioned above, I tried alexbt's solution using single quotes but it did not work for me.

Adding `file:\` at the beginning of the path with single quotes worked just fine.

```
ssl:
    trust-store-location: 'file:\F:\Spring-boot-projects\Kafka\ssl\client.truststore.jks'
    trust-store-password: 12345678
    key-store-location: 'file:\F:\Spring-boot-projects\Kafka\ssl\client.keystore.jks'
    key-store-password: 12345678
```