# Setting correct absolute path in application yaml spring boot for file

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, yaml

I am trying to run a kafka code, and to do that I have setup some config in application.yaml file. The config also include pointing to the certificates.

When I have put values like:

```yaml
    ssl:
      key-password: xxxx
      keystore-location: 'file:\\C:\Users\xx\Downloads\stores\testclient.jks'
      keystore-password: dmlnvba
      truststore-location: 'file:\\C:\Users\xx\Downloads\stores\truststore.jks'
      truststore-password: xxxxx
```

I get errors like:

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:\C:\Users\xx\Downloads\stores\testclient.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:216) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:157) ~[?:?]
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:111) ~[?:?]
    at io.confluent.kafka.schemaregistry.client.security.SslFactory$SecurityStore.load(SslFactory.java:161) ~[kafka-schema-registry-client-6.0.0.jar:?]
```

I looked over into answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39049075/absolute-path-in-application-yml) but I am not sure why is it not working for me.

#### Update 2

When I do it like

```yaml
    ssl:
      key-password: xxxx
      keystore-location: 'C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/testclient.jks'
      keystore-password: dmlnvba
      truststore-location: 'C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/truststore.jks'
      truststore-password: xxxxx
```

```
Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: ServletContext resource [/C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/testclient.jks] cannot be resolved to absolute file path - web application archive not expanded?
    at org.springframework.web.util.WebUtils.getRealPath(WebUtils.java:344) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16] at org.springframework.web.context.support.ServletContextResource.getFile(ServletContextResource.java:194) ~[spring-web-5.3.16.jar:5.3.16]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.kafka.KafkaProperties$Ssl.resourceToPath(KafkaProperties.java:1222) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
    at org.springframework.boot.context.properties.PropertyMapper$Source.lambda$as$2(PropertyMapper.java:195) ~[spring-boot-2.6.4.jar:2.6.4]
```

> I notice that the path in the update 2 has `/C:` a slash appended to it.

How to fix this path issue ?

#### OS: Windows 10

#### Update 3

When I do it like what @xerx593 suggested :

```yaml
    ssl:
      key-password: xxxx
      keystore-location: 'file:C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/testclient.jks'
      keystore-password: dmlnvba
      truststore-location: 'file:C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/truststore.jks'
      truststore-password: xxxxx
```

I get

> Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: file:C:\Users\xx\Downloads\stores\testclient.jks (The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect)

Comment: @xerx593 : Thank you for your comment. I tried the suggested approach but now I am getting `The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect` . I have added `UPDATE 3` in my question for more insight

Comment: so with (springboot-web) `server.ssl.key-store` i got it working like so: `C:/Users/xerx/Desktop/TEST FOLDER/springboot.jks` (double backslash also works), no chance with `file:` neither with wrong file name/typos :)) (tested also with spring-boot:2.6.4 (and java 19!:))) ..now the question is only about kafka...

Comment: at least i found the line (hope correct version) to blame/debug: https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/blob/2e7500bb2daea563be009574f8a786fc65cc833c/client/src/main/java/io/confluent/kafka/schemaregistry/client/security/SslFactory.java#L161  ..so provide the same string as you would to `new FileInputStream(...);`

Comment: Have you tried `file://C:/Users/xx/Downloads/stores/testclient.jks`?

Answer (score 0):

maybe you could try the below sol. it can work in my case

```
config-path: "file:E:\\config"
```